# php redirection headers not sent through ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, header, callback

i am trying to send header from a php file that is called with ajax. problem is, when i validate all information with php, i want to redirect to another page but headers dont work! any ideas?

what the code does:

```
//------------- index.php
on click of input, function passes <input> values through $_POST to login.php
if($_SESSION[superman]==true){redirects to index_main.php}

//------------- login.php
all it does is validate forms and if login and password are correct, it sets $_SESSION [superman]=true
```

Comment: well, we make ajax call into external file that validates form, and then if everytihng is correct, it redirects with headers. headers dont work (even if i place them into the main file, from where the ajax function is being sent)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The redirect will only redirect *the Ajax call*! If you want to change the displayed page in the browser, you'll need to redirect using Javascript once the Ajax call completes.

- Make your Ajax call return a value indicating successful login (for example the string `true` or maybe the URL to the page you want to load)
- Check the return value of the Ajax call. If success, change `location.href` using Javascript.

Comment: vakstrom ok, so in the login.php we make <script> var vaka=true;</script>       and in main file, if(vaka==true){ location.href}..?   or would we need to make through an ajax call that would call back into the main file?

Comment: @semur that depends on how you are parsing the response.

Comment: it looks like this:    ajba.open("POST","php_reg/login.php?login_login="+str1+"&login_password="+str2,true);  is the request         login.php validates form and IF everything works, $_SESSION[redir_main]=true; ELSE echo "error";      the main file from which the responce was made sees if session is set and redirects with headers. IT WORKS, but only after i submit the values and REFRESH (then php realizes that there is a session registered, and redirects). i really dont know how else o explain...

Comment: You need to monitor the `readyState` of the call, and when the call is complete check the `responseText`. See the tutorial on this page: http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajaxxmlhttprequest.php